# Python 3, increment iterator

Tags: python, iterator, increment

I am processing a file line by line. Each line is checked, whether it contains a given text. Then, the next line needs to be assigned to the variable

```
i_line = iter(file)
for i_line in file:
    if text in i_line:
         #Go to the next line
         line = next(i_line, None) #A problem
         break
```

How to increment iterator i_line so as to point to the next line of the file? Both constructions do not work for me

```
next(i_line, None)
i_line.next()
```

Comment: `i_line` is just a regular string, not any kind of iterator, and in particular not related to the `file`'s internals.

Comment: By "the next line needs to be assigned to the variable", do you mean you want to record the next line for later processing, or do you want to advance to the next loop iteration?

Comment: Assigning `i_line = iter(file)` doesn't change how `i_line` is interpreted when you use it as a loop variable. You may want to refresh your knowledge of how `for` loops work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do `next(f)`.

Something like

```
>>> with open('testFile.txt', 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            if 'cat' in line:
                final_string = next(f)
```

So, for an input text file of

```
My Name is ABC.
I am a male.
My pet is a cat.
It's name is Ronald.
I hate rats.
```

The above code gives

```
>>> final_string
"It's name is Ronald.\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `line = file.next()` instead of `line = next(i_line, None)`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way of processing a file with `next()`.

```
with open(filename) as file:
    line = next(file, None)
    while line:
        print(line.strip())
        line=next(file, None)
```

Using both the `for line in file` iterator and `next` would print every other line:

```
with open(filename) as file:
    for line in file:
        print(line.strip())
        line = next(file,None)
```